# Is there any notation for a matrix representation of a bilinear form?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, bilinear-form

Let $V,W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$.

Let $H:V\times W \rightarrow F$ be a bilinear map and $\alpha=\{v_1,...,v_n\} , \beta=\{u_1,...,u_m\}$ be ordered bases for $V,W$ respectively.

Then there exists a unique $n\times m$ matrix $A$ such that $A_{ij}=H(v_i,u_j)$.

"We call $A$ the matrix representation of $H$ with respect to $\alpha,\beta$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are ordered bases for $V,W$ respectively."

Is there any notation for this matrix $A$?

I saw that some write this matrix as $[H]_\beta$ if $\alpha=\beta$ (so that $V=W$), but i don't know what notation would be used when $V\neq W$.

If there does not exist a such being widely used notation, i will use $[H]_{\alpha\times \beta}$ for this matrix.

Is it ok?

I mean, is there any field of mathematics which uses a notation $[]_{\alpha\times\beta}$ so that my notation would cause some confusion?

Comment: I would call the matrix $H$ with little abuse of notation, and $H_{ij}$ its elements.

Comment: "is there any field of mathematics which uses a notation" <- the answer is yes with high probability for any remotely sensible notation (and some others).

Comment: @Emanuele Your notation gives no information about which ordered bases is taken. That seems to bother when one wants to talk about how change of bases affect this matrix representation.

Comment: @Daniel thank you! Is there any notation for this matrix then?

Comment: There certainly are notations for it, but offhand, I don't remember any particular way to denote that matrix.